# How can I pass info about a referring page in a B2C claim

Tags: xml, azure-ad-b2c

I need to create a custom B2C user flow where the signup/signin token includes information about the referring page ie Apply Now button on a page for studying a particular course

I'm new to B2C and am not a coder so am only working by samples that I can find and documentation

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="utsb2c.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_signin" PublicPolicyUri="http://utsb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin" TenantObjectId="<tenant-id>">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>utsb2c.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Expecting a subject name to be passed to Salesforce during signup/signin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `state` parameter in the [authorization request](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) is intended for that purpose. It is part of the [OpenID Connect standard](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest):

[image]

And [fully supported by Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-authentication-requests):
[image]

You do not need a custom claim in id_token to transfer that information. If there is a particular reason to have this information in the id_token, please update your question.